# this.lastID devuelve null cuando hago un bind en el callback de un db.run() - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sqlite

Estoy tratando de insertar una serie de datos a una base de datos `SQLite3` desde `NodeJS` mediante un bucle con sentencias `INSERT`, sin embargo, necesito tener dentro de la función del `callback` la variable que utilizo para realizar el bucle `for`. Se me ha ocurrido hacer un bind con la función del `callback` pero entonces pierdo otras variables que se rellenan una vez que se ejecuta la sentencia `SQL` que son el `lastID` y el change. La parte del código correspondiente es la siguiente:

```
for(var i =0; i<listaCaidas.length;i++)
        {
            db.run("INSERT INTO Caidas (idHistoriaActual, Fecha, MomentoDia, Donde, MecanismoCaida, precisoValoracionMedica) VALUES (? ,? ,?, ?, ?, ?)", idHistoriaActual, listaCaidas[i].fecha, listaCaidas[i].momentoDia, listaCaidas[i].lugar, listaCaidas[i].mecanismoCaida, listaCaidas[i].valoracionmedica, function(err,rows){
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log("Surgió un error al tratar de insertar una caída \n");  res.status(500);
                                        res.status(0);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var idCaida = this.lastID;
                                        console.log("La caida que s eha insertado tiene id: " + this.lastID);
                                        console.log("El valor de i es: " + this.i);
                                        var listaSintomas = listaCaidas[this.i].listaSintomas;
                                        console.log("Añadimos las consecuencias de la caída \n");

                                    }
                                }.bind({ i : i}));
                            }

                        }
```

Con el código de arriba me devuelve correctamente la variable `i`, pero `this.lastID` me aparece como  `undefined`, sin quito el `.bind` el `this.lastID` tiene valor pero la `i` me aparece como `undefined`.

Espero vuestra ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

se me ocurre esta solución usando una immediately invoked function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listaCaidas.length; i++) {
(function (i) {
    db.run("INSERT INTO Caidas (idHistoriaActual, Fecha, MomentoDia, Donde, MecanismoCaida, precisoValoracionMedica) VALUES (? ,? ,?, ?, ?, ?)",
        idHistoriaActual,
        listaCaidas[i].fecha,
        listaCaidas[i].momentoDia,
        listaCaidas[i].lugar,
        listaCaidas[i].mecanismoCaida,
        listaCaidas[i].valoracionmedica,
        function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Surgió un error al tratar de insertar una caída \n");
                res.status(500);
                res.status(0);
            }
            else {
                var idCaida = this.lastID;
                console.log("La caida que s eha insertado tiene id: " + this.lastID);
                console.log("El valor de i es: " + i);
                var listaSintomas = listaCaidas[i].listaSintomas;
                console.log("Añadimos las consecuencias de la caída \n");

            }
        })
})(i);
}
```

Por supuesto esto es equivalente a definir el contenido del bucle como una función y llamarla con `i` como parámetro.

Esto resuelve el motivo por el que estabas usando `this.i` en lugar de `i`